# Selected item, doesn`t work

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I want to make a selected div on this page http://tinyurl.com/nknqlm9, I tried with div: active, but don t work, for this page I have used a iframe tag.

Comment: Add your relevant code to the question please.

Comment: `For more info, just ask`.. u must be kidding me...why don't you post all the relevant codes first

Comment: what do you want to do with that div?

Comment: i want to show the code, but you have a link, is a html file

Comment: So we have to check all your site to see what is going on? Well, not for me, GL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read this comment : *Hover is ok, but i want to remain activ that hover after I click on it*

Take the `hover` `class` a make a new one :

**CSS**

```
.active { /*css of the hover */ }
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass('active');
   //if you want to toggle it use toggleClass('active') instead of addClass.
});
```

Comment: +1 for attempting to answer poorly asked question!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `div:hover` if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Hover is ok, but i want to remain activ that hover after I click on it

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui +1 for attempting to answer poorly asked question!